# Links to comments in chat are not oneboxing

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, onebox

Posting a link to a comment as the sole body of a chat message allows the comment to be one-boxed. However this is currently not working.

[image]

Comment: Finally. Let's not fix that ...

Comment: [Post oneboxing](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50250803#50250803) is also b0rked.

Comment: Looks like [it's](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50251316#50251316) [fixed](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50251318#50251318).

Comment: @double-beep Confirmed (fixed) here too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be resolved. Copying my answer from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353217/164200):

> While debugging an issue on the Fortinet, we had to test something which resulted in some unintended consequences with DNS and lots of other things. It resulted in this service being unavailable, but it should be stable again soon.