# Failed to upload image; couldn't reach imgur (2020 edition)

Tags: bug, status-completed, uploader, imgur

I'm unable to upload any image due to the following error:

> Failed to upload image; couldn't reach imgur

https://imgur.com/ itself looks working. And I can upload image via their site. So here's proof for MSE:

> [image]

Comment: I repro-ed on Chrome, Win10 and now it just worked ... in the second attempt

Comment: I also repro'd just a moment ago, but now it appears to work. Odd.

Comment: @Spevacus yep. Looks fixed already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While debugging an issue on the Fortinet, we had to test something which resulted in some unintended consequences with DNS and lots of other things. It resulted in this service being unavailable, but it should be stable again soon.

Thanks for the report.