# Community Bulletin box (Blog posts, featured and hot meta questions) is not visible on sidebar

Tags: bug, status-completed, sidebar, community-bulletin

Links to blog posts, featured and hot meta questions have vanished from my sidebar today. I can see the same effect on other sites.

Is this a bug or a feature?

[image]

Comment: We're investigating.

Comment: [Looks like it's back already](https://i.imgur.com/9A6EblV.png).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We're still investigating what triggered it, but it's been resolved for the time being.

We believe it has to do with some [debugging of the Fortinet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353217/164200) which resulted in an issue with DNS, and other things.

Comment: Did you find out? It seems the bulletin is gone today again.